# How do I open Oracle Forms/Reports?

Tags: oracle, oracleforms, oraclereports

I have installed Fusion middelware infrastructure and then Oracle forms and Reports ontop of it with no errors but now I dont know how to open them? They have not appeared in my start menu and the documentation seems very complex.

Reading documentation

NA

NA

Comment: Are you asking about development tools (such as Forms Builder)? Or running existing Forms application?

Answer (score 0):

In the bin directory of your forms installation you find a process "frmbld.exe".
If you start that formsbuilder will start.
In the bin directory of your reports installation you find a process "rwbuilder.exe"
If you start that reportsbuilder will start.

Comment: Sorry but an executable file is not a "process".